# How to create thread pool to listen on tcp-server packet python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, thread-safety

I trying to create thread pool to make some action on the in-coming tcp packets simultaneously.

I didn't find any built-in thread-pool in python3. Also I read a little about `multiprocessing.Pool`, but it doesn't support memory-sharing. so I used `Queue` to simulate pooling for threads.

Is it better to create a queue for each thread?
Do anyone have suggestions or better solution to improve following custom thread-pool code?

```
import socketserver
import threading
from queue import Queue


class ThreadPool:
    tcp_queue = Queue()
    # redis = redis connection

    def __init__(self, thread_worker_numbers=10):
        for i in range(thread_worker_numbers):
            threading.Thread(target=self.worker).start()

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            packet = self.tcp_queue.get()
            print('thread: %s  received packet: %s' % (threading.current_thread().getName(), packet))
            # TODO do process on packet

    def queue(self, packet):
        self.tcp_queue.put(packet)

    def queue_count(self):
        return self.tcp_queue.qsize()


class TCPServerHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    thread_pool = ThreadPool()

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        packet = self.data.decode("utf-8")
        print(packet)
        self.thread_pool.queue(packet)
        # print("%s wrote: %s" % (self.client_address[0], packet))

        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(bytes('{ok: 1, msg:""}', 'utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 9999
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPServerHandler)
    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You should use https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html, which has both a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (Threading Backend) and a `ProcessPoolExecutor` (multiprocessing backend). I would really recommend you look into Twisted, which is exceedingly good at this type of task.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VooDooNOFX . its very good sugestion